# cluster centers very similar while dendogram shows high merge cost

Tags: r, clustering, distance, hierarchical-clustering, ward

I'm running a hierarchical cluster analysis (ward method, euclidean distance in the standardized variable space using `scale` function) and by looking at the dendogram, 4 cluster solution seems very reasonable, given the heights (costs) of the merging steps. However, once I plot the cluster centers, two clusters are ridiculously similar.

I've checked my code milion times and I can't figure out the bug and I was wondering is this even possible? Can it really be that those two clusters are so similar and yet, the merge step is so high (using ward criteria)?

here are the cluster centers, clusters 1 and 4 have almost identical centers
[image: cluster centers]

Here is the dendogram plot, clusters 1 and 4 should be the first two clusters from the left.
[image: clustering dendogram]

Comment: A remark: you highlighted 5, not 4 clusters on the dendro.

Comment: Ward should use *squared* Euclidean distance; and you may need to use sqrt(height) then.

Comment: It could be. Try simplifying the analysis. Pick 2 items from each cluster and recluster those 8 samples. What does that dendrogram look like?